# 2-Pair Ethernet Cable works only on one specific router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cat5, cat5e

I have an IP video doorbell that connects using a 2-pair telephone line. I have managed to connect it to my DSL router (Linksys WAG320N) successfully and connection is working fine with live streaming over internet.

Now, due to limited upload speed of my DSL router (only 512 Kbps) where I need a minimum of 1 Mbps upload line, I used a 4G Router but when I connect the same 2-pair line to the router (HUAWEI LTE CPE B593) it does not fire and the led light does not blink. Actually the Ethernet port status shows as disconnected. 
So, I tried connecting the line to a switch then to the DSL router, but again it does not connect and shows as disconnected. I tried different setups and the only thing that works is connecting direct to the DSL router! So all other routers/switches could not connect to this ethernet line.

So what I can conclude is that this is a hardware issue but not sure exactly why is that and how to enable the switch/4G router to be able to connect to the doorbell through this 2-pair Ethernet line (please note I used a 10/100 MB switch to eliminate Gigabit compatibility issues but still line will not fire)

Any ideas how to make this 2-pair cable connect to other routers/switches? is this related to some configuration in the router? or this is hardware compatibility with new routers/switches? would appreciate any suggestions ..

Comment: Perhaps the autosense 10/100/1000 doesn't know how to handle this type of connection.

Try connecting it to a computer where you can force 10/100/1000 full/half duplex in the settings, to figure out if that's the issue. You might have to make an adapter that puts the wires in different positions on the RJ-45 to get it to detect on other devices

Comment: My guess is that you have a wiring (polarity) error in the cable, and the DSL router is able to figure this out.  Being able to handle miswired cables is a feature of some hubs and routers.

Comment: Cloneman, I have tried your suggestion and it turns to be connecting when I change the settings to 10 MB full/half duplex. So how to go from here, is there a way to force certain port in the router/hub to 10MB? Any other suggestion?

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Can you post the pinout/colors of both ends of this 2-wire cable ? (On typical transparant plastic connectors you can usually see the colors of the individual wires.) Picture of the connectors on both ends would be great too. That would help to determine what is really going on.